# Encoding Error while writing HTML to txt file

Tags: java

I am downloading the source code of an html webpage and writing it back to a txt file. The output on the terminal looks correct but while writing into a file and reading the contents the file using gedit the contents look something like this :

<^@!^@D^@O^@C^@T^@Y^@P^@E^@ ^@h^@t^@m^@l^@ ^@P^@U^@B^@L^@I^@C^@ ^@"^@-^@/^@/^@W^@3^@C^@/^@/^@D^@T^@D^@ ^@X^@H^@T^@M^@L^@ ^@1^@.^@0^@ ^@T^@r^@a^@n^@s^@i^@t^@i^@o^@n^@a^@l^

I am reading the file line by line by using BufferedReader something like this :

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://example.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        // appending to get the complete html string 
    }
```

Then I am writing the contents using PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
pout.write(html); // here html is the appended html string
pout.close();
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: How are you writing to file? Looks like encoding or charset issue.

Comment: I am using PrintWriter to write to the file. I have added the code in the question for a clearer view.

Comment: Try to pass encoding to `InputStreamReader` constructor from sent header `Content-Type` or page murkup in `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the URL, you need to set the encoding to UTF-8 and while writing back, you should again mention that your encoding is UTF-8. The default encoding could be your system's encoding and might not handle the unicode characters well. Both the `InputStream` and `Outputstream` support encoding as an argument. So you might want to replace your `PrintWriter` with `OutputStream`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was with the encoding. I took the input/output of the URL as UTF-16 and it worked.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered (and not just the upvote)? This will prevent other users looking at the question from attempting to answer it again.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use apache IOUitls

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(file));

URL url = new URL("http://example.com"");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
    System.out.println("content-type: " + contentType);
    IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream("/folder/fileName.html"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`^@` is a byte 0, so you are reading with UTF-16, that seems to be your system default encoding.

Specify the encoding. The encoding from the header lines is decisive. If not specified, use the default Latin-1.

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://example.com");
URLConnection con = oracle.openConnection();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
if (encoding == 0 || encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("ISO-8859-1")) {
    encoding = "Windows-1252"; // Default is Latin-1, as Windows Latin-1
}
con.connect();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), encoding));
```

However you might consider a meta statement.